# IntelliJ code coverage runner - headless

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, command-line, code-coverage, headless

According to:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206842605-Running-IntelliJ-code-coverage-headless-on-Jenkins-

It is possible to use intellij code-coverage runner in a headless environment - i.e. Jenkins.

This is nice since IntelliJ reports much more accurate coverage results on new groovy code than e.g. Cobertura. And I can also collect information from Grails tests - unit and integration. However, I have no idea on how to set it up - gradle, maven, custom build-script or whatever - on Jenkins.

When IntelliJ runs Grails tests it fires the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java 
-XX:+TieredCompilation 
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 
-XX:CICompilerCount=3 
-Dgrails.full.stacktrace=true 
-Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false 
-Dgrails.build.listeners=org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.GrailsIdeaTestListener 
-Didea.launcher.port=7533 
"-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3\bin" -classpath C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath.jar 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.grails.cli.GrailsCli test-app -echoOut
```

Which indicates that IntelliJ should be installed to run it headless. Is it possible to execute the above command in a headless env?

I have tried unpacking intellij and by executing the following (slightly modified for linux) command:

```
java 
-XX:+TieredCompilation 
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 
-XX:CICompilerCount=3 
-Dgrails.full.stacktrace=true 
-Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dgrails.build.listeners=org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.GrailsIdeaTestListen r 
-Didea.launcher.port=7533 
-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/jenkins/idea/bin -classpath /tmp/classpath.jar 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.grails.cli.GrailsCli test-app -echoOut
```

it fails with:

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain` even with idea_rt.jar added to the command with "cp" flag.

Is this a goose chase, or could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `classpath.jar` on Windows? This file is automatically generated and links lots of jars via Manifest to avoid OS limitation for the maximum command line length. Your `/tmp/classpath.jar` either doesn't exist or doesn't link the dependencies correctly.

Final classpath would include several IDE jars from the `lib` directory, project classes from the output directory and dependencies, plugin jars, etc. In other words, everything required to run the app would be linked from the generated `classpath.jar` file.

Comment: I looked for it in the path specified, but it wasn't there. So I assumed it was generated runtime or something like that - didn't know what purpose it had. But with your explanation, it's probably needed. Will look further into it on windows :)

Comment: This file is removed when the process is stopped. Put a breakpoint in the app so that you can find the file before it's deleted.

Comment: Phew. Thats one hell of a file... Not sure this ever will "get good" on linux :)

Comment: Might be easier to use TeamCity which [supports code coverage](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Java+Code+Coverage). You can probably start the build via Jenkins and export results to it via the artifact.